# how to bind the return html data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

In django views I return

```
context['foo'] = 'bar'
return render_to_response('test.html', context_instance=context)
```

test.html is included by main.html

On ajax success I am attaching the test.html data into the div having id foobar of the main.html I want to attach the {{ foo }} variable with the main.html too.

```
success:function(data) {
    $('#foobar').html(data);
}
```

It attached the data with the `foobar element` of a template. There are some variable with the data I want to bind this it to original template. How should I bind those data with the original templates?

Comment: Define what you mean when you say "*template*".

Comment: template is any html file. say foo.html

Comment: you will need to provide more information on what this data is and what you want to bind it too.  It's certainly possible, but we need more info.  As a sidenote, it sounds like what you really want is to use XSL.

Comment: Yeah (@justk), what are these variables - are they js variables? certain HTML elements? can you also give us an example of what html response of the ajax request looks like...

Comment: @justkt; I updated my question with more info .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can do that like that:

```
var context = {
    foo: {
        id: 1
    }
}; 

$.get("template.html", function(result) {
    result = $(result);
    $("*", result).each(function() {
        var field = $(this).data("field");
        if (field) { // Is tag has "data-field" attribute?
            //Well, loop on context to find result.
            //e.g. result = context["foo"]["id"]

            var regExp = /([^.]+)/gi,
                o = context,
                match;
            while (match = regExp.exec(field)) { 
                var key = match[1];
                o = o[key];
            }

            $(this).text(o);
        }
    });
    $("body").append(result);
});
```

Template.html:

```
<div data-field="foo.ID"></div>
```

The second option's if you got more complex field names, you may wanna use [Pure](http://beebole.com/pure/).

Comment: Oh my. I think I didn't realized question. sorry.